# Нажатие на часть элемента TextView

Tags: android, textview

Есть `TextView`, в котором есть предложение.

Как реализовать `PopupWindow`, по нажатию на часть `TextView`, чтобы появился `PopupWindow` и в нём перевод нажатого слова?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [ClickableSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html)

Пример.

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hello World");
ClickableSpan span1 = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        // do some thing
    }
};

ClickableSpan span2 = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        // do another thing
    }
};

ss.setSpan(span1, 0, 4, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(span2, 6, 10, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

И добавьте `TextView` `android:clickable="true"`